# POSTing to an ASP MVC 4 site from a C# Windows application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm writing a Windows application that will communicate with an ASP MVC site.

The site has a controller method for POST requests that passes to it an object from my Model.

I have access to those same classes in my desktop application and was hoping that I would be able to create an object of the same type, then create an HTTP POST request, attach the object and send it to the site.

I found that the POST data is just key-value pairs that match the properties of the class so Property1=value1&Property2=value2 worked, however I'm stumped as to how to represent a list.

Is there some easy way to serialise the object into an HTTP request or would I have to make multiple requests for each item in the list?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **WebClient** to implement such behavior

```
string url = "your POST action url here";
NameValueCollection formData = new NameValueCollection();
formData["name"] = "John";
// add more form field / values here

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
byte[] responseBytes = webClient.UploadValues(url, "POST", formData);
string response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
```

However, this is not good practice. This kind of communication should be implemented with **web services** - if your application is designes well (for example you have service layer/repository), there is nothing easier than expose simple webservice side by side with MVC frontend.

Comment: I am making a web service. The web service returns JSON objects which are deserialised into objects in my application. My problem is serialising the object into POST data where it contains lists for sending from the application to the web service.

Comment: On what technology are you building it that you have to struggle with serialization? Why dont you use WCF and let it handle this low-level stuff for you ?